# In unordered_map of C++11, how to update the value of a particular key?

Tags: c++11, unordered-map

In Java's hashmap:

```
map.put(key, new_value)
```

will update the entry of key=key with new_value if it exists in the hashmap.

What's the correct way to do the similar thing in unordered_map of C++11?

I haven't found an API like updateXXX, and the documentation says the **unordered_map::insert** function will succeed only when there isn't any such pair with a key.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you know that the key is in the map, you can utilize `operator[]` which returns a reference to the mapped value. Hence it will be `map[key] = new_value`. Be careful, however, as this will insert a `(key, new_value)` if the key does not already exist in the map.

You can also use `find` which returns an iterator to the value:

```
auto it = map.find(key)
if(it != map.end()) 
    it->second = new_value;
```

Comment: Or `std::unordered_map::at`. It will throw `std::out_of_range` exception, if element with specified `key` does not exists.

Comment: Thanks! I used `unordered_map::const_iterator it = map.find(key)` and I got an error when tried to assign `new_value` to `it->second`. `auto` works perfect. I need learn more about C++..

Comment: @Yeclipse That's because you're using a `const_iterator` - this means that what the iterator is "pointing to" is `const` (that is, it can't be changed). Modify it to `unordered_map::iterator it = map.find(key)` and it will work - this is what `auto` is deducing it as.

Comment: The second part is wrong, `it->second` is not a reference. Assigning to it won't update the value in the map, only the value copy of the iterator.

Comment: @jturcotte The dereferencing operation on `*it` will give you back a reference, which will be a `std::pair<const K, T>&` for an `unordered_map<K, T>`.  Hence modifying `it->second` will modify the value that is stored in the container.

Comment: @yuushi Thanks for the explanation, you're right. I did a quick test but managed to make an unrelated mistake that prevented it from working.

Answer (score 4):

If the type `value` has no default constructor you can use:

```
map.emplace(key, new_value).first->second = new_value;
```

This also has all the other advantages of emplace vs [] operator and insert.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that Java's `map.put` inserted the element if it wasn't already in the map and updated it if it was in the map, see *[put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)*:

> put 
>   
>   public V put(K key, V value) 
>   
>   Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

This would be equivalent to [unordered_map::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator%5B%5D/):

> If k matches the key of an element in the container, the function returns a reference to its mapped value. 
>   
>   If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the key exists
2. Update the value by referencing the key

```
if(map.count(key)){
  map[key] = value;
}
```