# modify value of key in boost unordered_map

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map

I have a boost::unordered_map which I want to modify the value of a particular key. 
I have seen the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291897/in-unordered-map-of-c11-how-to-update-the-value-of-a-particular-key).

what makes my question different is that in my map key is a simple int and my value is std::vector. I want to update this value by inserting a new PoitCoord at the second position of the vector.

One solution is like that:

```
auto it = map.find(key);
if(it != map.end()) 
{
    std::vector<PointCoord> pntcrds = it->second;
    pntcrds.insert((pntcrds.begin()+1), new_value);
    it->second = pntcrds;
}
```

I am wondering if there is less verbose solution.

Comment: `it->second.insert( (pntcrds.begin()+1), new_value);`? However, you should make sure that the vector is not empty.

Comment: Please post code that compiles, you have typos.  And you never modify a key.  Why are you inserting at the 2nd position?

Comment: It is necessary to be inserted in the second position based on the algorithm I am using.

Comment: @JohannesS. Is it possible to inserted directly by calling map itself?

Comment: Well, the map does not have anything to do with the insertion, IIUC. You are only modifying a vector which happens to be stored in a map. You are not modifying the key of a map, but one of it's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map does not have anything to do with your insertion, if I understand your question correctly. You are only modifying a vector which happens to be *stored* in a map. You are not modifying the *key* of a map, but one of it's *values*.

So the short solution would be:

```
auto it = map.find(key);
if(it != map.end() && !it->second.empty() ) 
{
    it->second.insert( (pntcrds.begin()+1), new_value);
}
```

If you know that the key exists in your map, you can shorten this to:

```
std::vector<PointCords> & pntCords = map[key];
if( ! pntCords.empty() )
   pntCords.insert( pntCords.begin()+1, new_value );
```

NB: If you use the second method and the key does not yet exist, a default constructed (=empty)  `std::vector<PointCords>` will be inserted into the map.

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the key iteration position then update directly the found key by

```
it->second.insert( (pntcrds.begin()+1), new_value);
```

but you have to be sure that you've found the iteration and as @Johannes said  your vector is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a very simple solution, that covers all the scenarios you might think about. And it is

```
myMap[key].insert(pntcrds.begin()+1);
```

If the key does not exist, it will be inserted. otherwise, the value will be updated to the new one;

But you **must** make sure you have at least one element in your vector. Otherwise, it will crash.

A similar trick would be

```
myMap[key].push_back(new_value); // appends to the end of the vector
```

Comment: If the key does not exist, it will be inserted; otherwise, the container will be unchanged.

Comment: @JamesKanze No: https://ideone.com/HWYO57 `operator[]` returns a non-const reference, which can of course be modified. In my case, by `push_back()` or `insert()`

Comment: My bad.  I saw the `insert`, and was thinking of `std::map<>::insert`.  `myMap[key]` does create the element if it isn't there.